# Downloading Image extremely slow

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create my first little chat app. The users can change their profile picture when registering. I'm trying to display the profile picture each time the users chats with another users. Everything works but the problem is that some pictures are extremely slow. This causes that some messages will display fast and others very slow.

My Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    messagesTableView.delegate = self
    messagesTableView.dataSource = self
    messagesTableView.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = true

    getMessages()
}

    func getMessages() {
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let messagesReference = ref.child("Messages")

    // GETTING THE MESSAGES AND USERNAMES
    messagesReference.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

            let usernameReference = ref.child("Usernames").child(dictionary["Sender"] as! String)

            // CONVERTING THE USERNAME INTO THE UID
            usernameReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot2) in

                if let dictionary2 = snapshot2.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    let uid = dictionary2["UID"] as! String

                    let uidReference = ref.child("Users").child(uid)

                    // GETTING THE PROFILE IMAGE LINK
                    uidReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot1) in

                        if let dictionary1 = snapshot1.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                            let imageLink = dictionary1["Image Link"] as! String

                            // DOWNLOADING THE PROFILE IMAGE FROM THE LINK
                            let url = URL(string: imageLink)
                            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

                                if(error != nil){
                                    print(error as Any)
                                    return
                                }

                                let profileImage = UIImage(data: data!)

                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    let message = Messages()
                                    message.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
                                    message.profileImage = profileImage

                                    self.messages.append(message)

                                    self.messagesTableView.reloadData()
                                }
                            }.resume()
                        }
                    }, withCancel: nil)
                }
            }, withCancel: nil)
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
}

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return messages.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cellId")

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let message = self.messages[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = message.Sender
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = message.Message
        cell.imageView?.image = message.profileImage
    }

    return cell
}
```

This image is downloading and displaying fast:
-> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/chat-62eba.appspot.com/o/ProfileImages%2F766FB2E4-9153-4F99-81B2-14B2E3677459.png?alt=media&token=306e32e5-21b6-4ff5-918b-79c6173f0ae9

And this one is downloading and displaying extremely slow:
-> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/chat-62eba.appspot.com/o/ProfileImages%2F0B758D09-58FE-4771-BA29-16FB0EAB2FFD.png?alt=media&token=8d886b45-dd14-4157-b647-217122b6d331

I've searched for hours to find a solution but haven't found one yet. I hope someone can help me! Thanks

Comment: The slow image is a 11.2 MB image (vs. a few KB the other image) ! ... This will always be slow.

You should try optimise (in terms of size) what can be uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code you are using Firebase, so I guess you have no additional backend. The issue is really at the upload-side. You **need** to optimise the size and thus, crop the image.

```
func resize(image: UIImage, size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {

    let scale = size.width / image.size.width
    let height = image.size.height * scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: size.width, height: height))
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: height))

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

The second image is too heavy. That's why it is taking time. What you should do is crop the image dimension up to 100x100 or 200x200 when user is uploading it for first time. So, all the profile pictures in your database will be of same dimensions and will take less time.

Even your small image is of 720x720 = 37kb and the other one 3000x2002 = 11.2 Mb. So you see what is happening.

More over if you don't want to crop the picture when user is uploading you will have to do that on your server that will keep thumbnails of every image. So what will happen then is Original picture will be stored in database but you will fetch thumbnails of small size. But that depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for helping!